# Gulp 4 - Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`

Tags: gulp-4, non-volatile

I use gulp 4 and trying to generate build with it , I am using gulp-build command .I am getting  Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`  error every time . I use systemjs in also( just mentioning ).previous questions posted here did not give me the expected answer .

```
  "gulp": "4.0.0",
    "gulp-cache-bust": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify": "0.0.15",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "3.2.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
```

But I am getting an error saying  Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`

I want a successful build , but I am getting

```
[12:59:40] Using gulpfile D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\gulpfile.js
[12:59:40] Starting 'build'...
[12:59:40] Starting 'clean'...
[12:59:40] Finished 'clean' after 83 ms
[12:59:40] Starting 'copyNodeDependencies'...
[12:59:40] Finished 'copyNodeDependencies' after 8.09 ms
[12:59:40] Starting 'bundleDependencies'...
[12:59:40] Starting 'bundleApp'...
Executing bundleApp
[12:59:40] Finished 'bundleDependencies' after 20 ms
bundleApp completed successfully
[12:59:54] Finished 'bundleApp' after 13 s
[12:59:54] Starting 'compileTs'...
[12:59:54] Starting 'copyVendor'...
[12:59:55] Finished 'copyVendor' after 701 ms
D:/newChanges/CreditCard/Presentation Tier/CreditCard.Web.UI/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(20,1): error TS1084: Invalid 'reference' directive syntax.
[13:00:00] TypeScript: 1 syntax error
[13:00:00] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[13:00:00] Finished 'compileTs' after 6.08 s
[13:00:00] Starting 'copyVendor'...
[13:00:00] Starting 'bundleVendor'...
[13:00:03] Finished 'bundleVendor' after 3.48 s
[13:00:03] Finished 'copyVendor' after 3.49 s
[13:00:03] Starting 'bundleCss'...
[13:00:04] Finished 'bundleCss' after 733 ms
[13:00:04] Starting 'copyContent'...
[13:00:04] Finished 'copyContent' after 3.84 ms
[13:00:04] Starting 'generateBuild'...
[13:00:04] Finished 'generateBuild' after 4.74 ms
[13:00:04] Starting 'buildCacheBusting'...
[13:00:04] Finished 'buildCacheBusting' after 2.83 ms
[13:00:04] Finished 'build' after 24 s
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`
    at DestroyableTransform.normalize [as _transform] (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\dest\prepare.js:16:17)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:184:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:172:83)
    at doWrite (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:428:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:417:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:334:11)
    at Pumpify.Duplexify._write (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:208:22)
    at doWrite (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:428:64)
    at writeOrBuffer (D:\newChanges\CreditCard\Presentation Tier\CreditCard.Web.UI\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:417:5)
    at Pumpify.Writable.write (D:\newCh
```